# How to fix a count() in a query with a "group by" clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, zeos

I have a function that gets a SQL code and inserts a count field in it and executes the query to return the number of rows in it. The objective is to have a dynamic SQL code and be able to get its record count no matter what code it has, because I use it in a registry filter window and I never know what code may be generated, because the user can add as many filters as he/she wants.

But as I use the `group by` clause, the result is wrong because it is counting the number of times a main registry appears because of the use on many `join` connections.

The result of that code above should only one row with a columns with `10` as result, but I get a new table with the first columns with a `2` in the first row and a `1` on the other rows.

If I take off the `group by` clause I will receive a `11` as a count result, but the first row will be counted twice.

What should I do to get a single row and the correct number?

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(*) QUERYRECORDCOUNT, // this line appears only in the Count() function 
 ARTISTA.*,
 CATEGORIA.NOME AS CATEGORIA,
 ATIVIDADE.NOME AS ATIVIDADE,
 LOCALIDADE.NOME AS CIDADE,
 MATRICULA.NUMERO AS MAP

FROM
 ARTISTA
 LEFT JOIN PERFIL ON PERFIL.REGISTRO = ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID
 LEFT JOIN CATEGORIA ON CATEGORIA.CATEGORIA_ID = PERFIL.CATEGORIA
 LEFT JOIN ATIVIDADE ON ATIVIDADE.ATIVIDADE_ID = PERFIL.ATIVIDADE
 LEFT JOIN LOCALIDADE ON LOCALIDADE.LOCALIDADE_ID = ARTISTA.LOCAL_ATIV_CIDADE
 LEFT JOIN MATRICULA ON MATRICULA.REGISTRO = ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID

WHERE 
 ((ARTISTA.SIT_PERFIL <> 'NORMAL') AND (ARTISTA.SIT_PERFIL <> 'PRIVADO'))
GROUP BY
 ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID
ORDER BY 
 ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID;
```

Comment: If you *always* LEFT JOIN, you could simply select `COUNT(*) FROM ARTISTA WHERE...` without selecting the extra rows and the extra joins.

Comment: The thing is that my function will receive SQL code with any number of fields and join and it has to alter the SQL to put the "count" in a way that the result would be the same as it was when untouched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This always gives you the number of rows for any query you have:

```
Select count(*) as rowcount from
(

     Paste your query here

) as countquery
```

Comment: It's not that efficient as if you proposed to use `COUNT(DISTINCT ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID)` and remove all the joins. In this case - it makes sense to rewrite a query in a proper way not just blindly wrap it with what you proposed. So, personally I wouldn't recommend your solution

Comment: Sure, you can rewrite your query for that. Just add count(*) and remove the `group by`. I just offered a solution that should always work, and doesn't require you to rewrite your query if you only want to know how many records you'll get.

Comment: "and doesn't require you to rewrite your query if you only want to know how many records you'll get" --- and it's terrible inefficient. There is no reason to leave the parts of query that don't influence on result.

Comment: Hmm, it **could be** terribly inefficient. When it turns out to be, do something about it. Until then, we're talking about premature optimization.

Comment: not actually. Until that we're talking about query that makes no sense. It's not an optimization, it's about what you're querying. Why to `LEFT JOIN` if you don't need it? Do you also in your code add some random pieces to queries just for fun?

Comment: Anyway - you have enough reputation to see my deleted answer. Compare mine query and yours. Then think for a second.

Comment: Sure you can optimize this query for performance, and yes, you can remove almost everything if all you want to do is count. That's clear to everyone. I just gave a generic solution to the problem of the OP, which was to get the rowcount.  Of course nobody should directly apply it blindly in all situations.

Comment: "Of course nobody should directly apply it blindly in all situations" --- I bet that's what OP did ;-) But anyway, I don't think it's an optimization. It's just a common sense for me.

Comment: I get your point that you can get the same result with a query that is more efficient.  The user has a query, and wants to know how many records it returns. You can rewrite the query into something that returns a record count, or you can simply run the original query and count the results. Both have advantages and disadvantages so none is the Right or Wrong way to do it. I think you would always do the former, the OP is now going to do the latter forever :), and others should just pick what's right for the situation.

Comment: well, now it looks like: someone in aqualung came to you for you to teach him how to ski. And you proposed to get on the ski and other stuff over swimming suite. For some people it (a person in aqualung on ski) may be acceptable, and I see it as a nonsense.

Comment: Haha, now you're exaggerating. It's more like: somebody asks how to stay dry. Your solution: change your clothes to a swimming suit before you go out. You can even leave socks and underwear off because you don't need them for this. My solution: take an umbrella. It's extra overhead, but it always works without requiring extra modifications.  When you go diving, pick your solution, when you just walk to your car in the rain, use my solution. Depending on the situation, either can be useful solutions. It's not as black and white as you're making it sound.

Comment: Anyway, interesting exchange of views. You do make a good point about performance. That should not be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Since your are GROUPING BY `ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID`, `COUNT(*) QUERYRECORDCOUNT` will return records count for each `ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID` value.

If you want GLOBAL count, then you need to use a nested query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QUERYRECORDCOUNT 
    FROM (SELECT 
     ARTISTA.*,
     CATEGORIA.NOME AS CATEGORIA,
     ATIVIDADE.NOME AS ATIVIDADE,
     LOCALIDADE.NOME AS CIDADE,
     MATRICULA.NUMERO AS MAP

    FROM
     ARTISTA
     LEFT JOIN PERFIL ON PERFIL.REGISTRO = ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID
     LEFT JOIN CATEGORIA ON CATEGORIA.CATEGORIA_ID = PERFIL.CATEGORIA
     LEFT JOIN ATIVIDADE ON ATIVIDADE.ATIVIDADE_ID = PERFIL.ATIVIDADE
     LEFT JOIN LOCALIDADE ON LOCALIDADE.LOCALIDADE_ID = ARTISTA.LOCAL_ATIV_CIDADE
     LEFT JOIN MATRICULA ON MATRICULA.REGISTRO = ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID

    WHERE 
     ((ARTISTA.SIT_PERFIL <> 'NORMAL') AND (ARTISTA.SIT_PERFIL <> 'PRIVADO'))
    GROUP BY
     ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID
    ORDER BY 
     ARTISTA.ARTISTA_ID);
```

In this case, you may not need to select those many columns.

If you need to retrieve the all records count with details, then better to use two separate queries.